# How can I redirect a user to a different part of my web application within a function that sends a cookie to the browser?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to edit the block of code below so that it will redirect the browser to the main page of my web application ("/") after the function is executed. I have tried adding "location: '/'" to the res.status(200) object, but that did not work (nothing happens). I also tried adding res.redirect('URL') to the code, that did not work either. Any help would be very much appreciated. Please go easy on me, I'm new to this.

```
exports.logout = (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('jwt', 'loggedout', {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 1000),
    httpOnly: true
  });
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer here since the comment placeholder text says to avoid answering questions in comments (and comments don't allow for neat code).

On the client side, check for the response status. If it is successful, redirect..

```js
// Some client-side sudo code
const resp = await fetch('mywebsite.com/logout', { options });
const logoutResult = await resp.json();

if (logoutResult.status === 'success') {
  // Redirect to "/" on successful logout
  window.location = 'mywebsite.com';
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or you could just redirect from Express like:

```js
exports.logout = (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('jwt', 'loggedout', {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 1000),
    httpOnly: true
  });
  // res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });
  res.redirect(200, "/");
};
```

Comment: Matt, thank you so much! This worked. I couldn't get it working at first. I was trying to use the client side solution that you offered... then I realized I had to re-bundle my code (I'm using Parcel for that). After that, it was working perfectly. Thank you again. This made my day!

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it working. In all honesty, redirecting via express (like the edit I. My answer shows) is going to be the 100% best bet. What happens if you try that?